# Java remove all non alphanumeric character from beginning and end of string

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, alphanumeric

I know how to replace ALL  non alphanumeric chars in a string but how to do it from just beginning and end of the string?

I need this string:

"theString,"

to be:

theString

replace ALL  non alphanumeric chars in a string:

```
s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "");
```

Comment: How many from the beginning and from the end?

Comment: post an example please

Comment: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#trimFrom(java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `^` (matches at the beginning of the string) and `$` (matches at the end) anchors:

```
s = s.replaceAll("^[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+$", "");
```

Comment: What's that `\\s` doing in there? I know OP had it, but it was wrong then and it's wrong now.

Comment: @DavidConrad, `\\s` will match any whitespace character. I thought it was OP's intention to exclude alpha-numeric characters and space characters, so I didn't touch it.

Comment: Exactly, that's why it's wrong. OP said "replace ALL non alphanumeric chars in a string". It's a negated set, so it will replace anything EXCEPT a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and any whitespace character. So it will leave in whitespace.

Comment: I think OP was trying to match UP TO a space, and didn't get how sets work. I guess I could be wrong.

Comment: @falsetru does this strip ALL non alphanumeric from beginning and end of the string or just one in beginning and end?

Comment: @Mike, It removes **all** non alphanumeric + non whitespace from the beginning and the end of the string. (I used `+`). If you want to remove only `one`, remove `+`.

Comment: Just a note: Although this did work, I had to replace with my own parser because the regex expression was just too expensive over thousands of iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
s.replaceAll("^[^\\p{L}^\\p{N}\\s%]+|[^\\p{L}^\\p{N}\\s%]+$", "")
```

Instead of:

```
s.replaceAll("^[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+$", "")
```

Where `p{L}` is any kind of letter from any language.
And `p{N}`is any kind of numeric character in any script.
For use in Latin-based scripts, when non-English languages are needed, like Spanish, for instance: éstas, apuntó; will in the latter become; stas and apunt. The former also works on non-Latin based languages.
For all Indo-European Languages, add `p{Mn}` for Arabic and Hebrew vowels:

```
s.replaceAll("^[^\\p{L}^\\p{N}^\\p{Mn}\\s%]+|[^\\p{L}^\\p{N}^\\p{Mn}\\s%]+$", "")
```

For Dravidian languages, the vowels may surround the consonant - as opposed to Semitic languages where they are "within" the character - like  ಾ. For this use `p{Me}` instead. For all languages use:

```
s.replaceAll("^[^\\p{L}^\\p{N}^\\p{M}\\s%]+|[^\\p{L}^\\p{N}^\\p{M}\\s%]+$", "")
```

See [regex tutorial for a list of Unicode categories](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Answer (score -1):

This removes all the non-alphanumeric characters

```
s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

Comment: This removes all the non-alphanumeric characters

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Answer (score -1):

```
yourString=yourString.replaceAll("^\\W+|\\W+$","");
```

Answer (score -1):

Guava's [CharMatcher](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) provides a concise solution:

```
CharMatcher.javaLetterOrDigit().negate().trimFrom(input);
```